# Cloud Function queries Firestore but returns empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I am building a cloud function, which accepts a customerID, filters documents based on the customerID and returns the list of documents. Sadly it returns an empty array. I'm sure this is a simple fix.

Here is the cloud function:

```
export const getCalendarItems = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const uid = data.uid;

  if (context.auth) {

    let array = [{}];

    const ref = admin.firestore().collection("photoshoots");
    const query = ref.where("customerID", "==", uid);
    query.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
        array.push({
          ...documentSnapshot.data(),
          key: documentSnapshot.id,
        });
      });
    });

    return array;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Here is the code when I call it from the client side.

```
const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;

functions()
      .httpsCallable("getCalendarItems")({
        uid: uid
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
      });
```

Also here is a screen shot of Firestore.

[Screenshot of firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k655m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your function.

First, you shouldn't use `onSnapshot()` to query in Cloud Functions.  Use [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html#get) instead to perform a query a single time.  `onSnapshot()` attaches a listener to receives updates in real time, and that's not what you want here.

Second, your function needs to return a promise that resolves with the data to send to the client.  `get()` returns a promise with a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) object.  You will need to use that to get the list of documents that matched your query.  You can use that list to send back results to the client.

The function code you want will look significantly different than what you have now, after you make the recommended changes.

Comment: Glad it works.  On Stack Overflow, it's conventional to mark answers as correct and upvote them if they were helpful to you.